# Google Maps API Location Express: Do you embed the script in your layout file along with the code for initializing a map?

Tags: javascript, express, google-maps, google-api, handlebars.js

I'm trying to have a map show up on a certain webpage route. I am drawing on three different Google Maps APIs in order to have an autocomplete search bar and to also show the selected location on an actual map. I read somewhere that the APIs can only be on the frontend and not the backend, meaning they belong in a script in my main HTML file. Is this correct?

I thought I might have to stick the functions and objects within the specific route I want the map to be on, and then pass them on to use them in the view (?) but that didn't seem to be working. Nothing is being output but I followed the CSS specifications, and enabled billing, so my API key should be correct, and I enabled the desired APIs.

I am using express + node + standard protocols to serve up my routes, and handlebars to structure the pages, and to pass any objects I am taking from the database.

Also using JS, in case that wasn't clear.

Comment: APIs are a way to get data from somewhere, so they are used in the front and backend. In your case, you are using the Google Maps library, which uses Google's API, which creates something on the front, so that's where you'd use it, so, yes, embed your script in your HTML. Lastly, Express and NodeJS are JS techs, so it was implied you are using JS :)

Comment: Thank you! Yes, true, I agree that was overkill. I thought I was doing something wrong in terms of the architecture but it turned out to be an innocent CSS mistake that was wreaking havoc.